# Python module for merging 16 bit images to high dynamic range image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I have a series of 16bit images with varying exposure times, which are partly overexposured and which I want to merge to a high dynamic range image in python. I know that there is the `cv2` module which I loaded, but I figured out that this one is only working with 8 bit images. So does anybody know a module for merging 16 bit `uint` image to a high dynamic range picture or does anybody know a way how to merge 16 bit images to and high dynamic range image with OpenCV?

Comment: OpenCV has HDR support; voting to close this as off-topic.

Comment: Yeah but only for 8bit images and I have 16bit images.

Comment: Maybe something like Python `ImageMagick` could work ... it does HDR above 16-bit I think... https://wiki.python.org/moin/ImageMagick

Answer (score 0):

You shall read the images with the cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED set on, e.g.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider using numpy and the Python Imaging Library (PIL or Pillow) to load the images as arrays, and then do your normalization and combination as array operations.

This chapter has some examples of how to manipulate things: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-computer-vision/9781449341916/ch01.html

For example, to load an image as a 32-bit integer numpy array:

```
from PIL import Image
from numpy import *

im = array(Image.open('picture.jpg').convert('I'))
```

Comment: since I am using nearly the whole dynamic range of the single 16bit pictures I would lose image quality, wouldnt I?

Comment: No, not at all.